# iPhone - change UINavigationController's bar traslucent on stack view

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to change the style of my navigation bar from a not-root view. How can I do that?

I use the:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
```

but doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

This code is fine. It would have to be a problem with another part of the code.

Comment: Most likely in the app. delegate (or wherever you declared your UINavigationController). Impossible to say for sure though.

Comment: Probably I miss some important steps... How we usually do this??

Comment: For example... if I write " self.title = hello " all works fine... :(

Comment: Try checking the class reference for UINavigationController. They might give you some helpful tips there.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try immediatly. :)

Comment: Alright. Be sure to tell me if you find anything helpful. Isn't Apple so nice to its developers for those class references? They are SO helpful ;)